# Android & MySQL: Get mysql_insert_id() and retrieve it in Android Activity

Tags: php, android

Hi I have connected a MySQL in a server with and Android application using JSON. I have a table called products where the primary key is and id which is auto_increment. When I insert a new product I would like to get that Id in my android Activity but I don't know how to retrieve it in PHP nor Android.
Here is some code:
Create Product Script

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");
```

Where should I put `mysql_insert_id()` ?

Finally, how could I get that `mysql_insert_id()` in my android activity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should come right below your `insert` query, save the last insert id to a variable and echo the variable out in your json string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is easy:

```
// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");
$insertedId = mysql_insert_id();
```

How do you send this id to your android app? The same way that you send everything else: JSON. I don't know what you usually send to your app, but this can be as easy as

```
echo json_encode($insertedId);
```

The usual disclaimer: Do not use the MYSQL extension anymore, it will be removed from PHP in the near future. Use Mysqli (i = improved) instead, or PDO.

Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks! Never ever put data unescaped directly into SQL, either use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or use prepared statements.

Comment: Many thanks Sven, I got it working finally. Thanks also for the piece of advise, I will investigate in those 2.